# 403 forbidden access is denied error occurring when consume web API in other computer in a LAN

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2, publish, http-status-code-403

I need to access a web API to access a different computer which is in a local network. For that purpose I publish that API and hosted by IIS. my computer and the other computer (which is going to access the API) pinged without any error and also I already accessed this API through the other computer successfully. but unfortunately ***today on words*** I could not be able to access it.

this is the error that occurred:
[image]

I tried lot of things according to the following order, but it doesn't work out.

- Added `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to my `web.config`(in web API publish folder).
- Read,write,modify permissions to `Network Service,IUSR,IIS_IUSRS`.
- Disable virus guard firewall.

This error will appear in the other computer (which I am using to access the API).

**Please be noted:** I able to access this API yesterday, But today onwards I could not be able to access it.

Comment: Have you enabled Windows Authentication for the virtual directory of Web API in the IIS?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I'm using windows 10 Home edition. Windows 10 Home edition does not support windows authentication in IIS.

Comment: Learn which 403 you hit first, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

Is your API running in your local machine? 
if not check your apppoolidentity.
did you changed LAN PasswordToday?